# Android FrameLayout can't set a View visible when it's initially set to invisible

Tags: java, android, visibility, android-framelayout

I have met a very strange issue in android FrameLayout.

I am trying a very simple game which has a SurfaceView, and when the game ends, I want to popup another view on top probably displaying some text. This is very similar to android sample lunarlander code. However I can't get it work. Here is the strange issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/game_frame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.tmh.FunMatch.MainGamePanel
  android:id="@+id/game_panel"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <com.tmh.FunMatch.MyText
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:text="test"
      android:visibility="invisible"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:textColor="#88ffffff"
      android:textSize="24sp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

For above FrameLayout, I want to show the second TextView when game finished. However it won't show after I call TextView.setVisibility(VISIBLE).

I did a lot experiment, if I initially set the TextView as VISIBLE, then at some point set it to INVISIBLE in the code. (My understanding is the TextView must be initially showed on the screen once then I turned it into INVISIBLE). If I did so, when the game finished, the TextView will be correctly shown.

I highly doubt it's an android bug. I changed android LunarLander code, I don't know why LunarLander did work and show the Text on the screen.

If anyone had run into the same issue, please tell me what's wrong with my code or is there a hidden bug?

Thanks

Comment: Try it with a standard textview instead of your custom one

Comment: It still doesn't work. I use the custom textview just in order to see if the onDraw method is ever called.

Comment: Update: I finally found the problem. It's definitely an android bug. Whenever you want to make a initially "INVISIBLE" view visible, you need to reset the resource in that view. For example, if you want to make a TextView visible, make sure you call setText() immediately after you call setVisibility(VISIBLE). If you want to make a ImageView visible, call setImageResource(). Even you already have those set in xml file. You need to call it again.

Comment: I've just hit the same issue (with ImageView), it is still there even with ICS. In case someone is looking for the solution - calling requestLayout() at least once on the view after making it visible. You can also see this effect when you click "Request layout" in Hierarchy Viewer tool (that's how I found it).